# Error installing Magento 2 with sample data (max_execution_time is 18000)

Tags: magento2, installation, sample-data

The installation reaches 90% before the error below. If I click retry, it comes back with the same error after 2mins 41secs.

[image: at 90%]

Other info:

- I am using the Magento-CE-2.0.2+sample_data-2016-01-28-02-39-03.zip file uploaded to my server and then extracted and run via
  mydomain.com/setup.
- My host said sql max_allowed_packet is set to 256M (edit: I have confirmed this via SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';)
- There is nothing in the php error log
- PHP version 5.5.32
- user.ini file has the following settings:

  memory_limit=256M &  max_execution_time=18000
- I've also tried deleting the whole installation and database and starting from scratch

Comment: What if you install sample data from command line?

Comment: max_execution_time needs to be 18000 not 1800. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_70pct.html. 

"My host said sql max_allowed_packet is set to 256M": can you verify this by executing this query: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`?

Comment: sorry, yes, it is set to 18000, I just checked my user.ini file

The query shows: max_allowed_packet  268435456

Comment: I'm not familiar with installing from command line, I've only ever used ftp and file manager in cPanel. I will look into this. I'm more worried that something isn't set up correctly and may cause other issues in the future.

Comment: I have checked with host and I do not have access to command line or SSH on a shared server and composer is not installed either. Is there another way to install sample data?

Comment: @pnx Try this http://stackoverflow.com/q/30753674/1616003

Answer (score 1):

Improve the limits in your `.htaccess`, if you are using **Apache**.

```
php_value memory_limit 2768M
php_value max_execution_time 218000
php_value max_allowed_packet 500M
```